# Fixed footer bar - Android HTML5 Phonegap app?

Tags: android, css, cordova, sticky-footer

Can anyone recommend the best method to create a fixed (sticky footer) footer nav bar within a HTML5 Android Phonegap app?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to scroll the area above the footer, iScroll is worth looking at:

[cubiq.org/iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Comment: And I would add to make sure to use iScroll 4. It's a significant upgrade. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: Almost works - but the footer bar doesnt stic to the bottom of the page - it's about 40px off!  Cant for the life of me work out why!  Its driving me nuts

Comment: worked eventually - seems you need to alter the footer class to position:static to get it to fix to the footer when using phonegap!

Answer (score 2):

Try using jquerymobile 1.1, `data-position=fixed attribute`

you can find example over here:-
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html